# Couldn't fetch return value (0 or 1) from stored procedure.?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I am returning 0 and 1 from a stored procedure like following. How can I fetch it in c# asp.net file?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[crudprocedure] 

    @getusername        varchar(20),
    @getfirstname       varchar(20),
    @getlastname        varchar(20),
    @getaddress         varchar(20)
 as 
 begin
IF not exists (select username from crudtable where username=@getusername)
begin 
insert into crudtable(username,firstname,lastname,address) 
values (@getusername,@getfirstname,@getlastname,@getaddress)
return 0
end
else
return 1
end
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: do `SELECT 0 As RetValue` and `SELECT 1 As RetValue` and use datareader to get that value in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server - then try this code here:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("...put your connection string here..."))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.crudprocedure", conn))
{
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   cmd.Parameters.Add("@getusername", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "test";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@getfirstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "test";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@getlastname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "test";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@getaddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "test";

   // define additional paramter of Direction = ReturnValue
   cmd.Parameters.Add("RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

   // open connection, execute stored proc, close connection
   conn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();

   // fetch the value of the "ReturnValue" parameter
   int returnValueInt = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["RETURN_VALUE"].Value);
}
```

Basically, since you're sending back that value using `RETURN 1` from the stored procedure, you need to add an additional parameter to your `SqlCommand` object that has a `.Direction` of `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`.

That parameter will be set to the value that you send back from the stored procedure using `RETURN ....`